# Setting an absolute file path outside of project foler for src value in an audio tag in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have an application where a user uploads an audio file in the frontend, it is sent to the backend and stored in a file system and the path (and other metadata for the file) is stored in MongoDB. Other users can now access this file, to do that I retrieve the metadata (which has the path) and attempt to render the audio file in the page as follows:

`test.AudioURL` contains the absolute path to the file on the shared filesystem of the local network. For simplicity, let's assume it's on the same machine, say `/home/user/projectfilesystem/audiofile.mp3`

```html
<audio controls src={test.AudioURL}>
    Your browser does not support the
    audio element.
</audio>
```

Since React does not allow us to refer to any file outside of the project directory, the file does not show up in the page. Is there a workaround for this? Copying the whole file again back into the project directory seems inefficient (especially when there are 100's of clients in a network trying to access this file).

Comment: Is your server user i.e. www-data for Apache can Access to this file?

Comment: once the file is uploaded to server it should be accessible via some url, not the path to file system, something like: http://yourserverhostname/data/audiofile.mp3

Comment: @NhutDinhBa Yes, my bad, I was testing using the file on my machine, but on the server your method works fine, thanks!